# issue with HTML/CSS modal window

Tags: html, css, popupwindow, simplemodal

i have designed a modal window in HTML/CSS and on my localhost that modal window is working fine but on my remote server i can not use tabs on the modal window here i am posting the complete css i am using to create this modal window.

```
 *emphasized text*.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
width: 450px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 15px 20px 13px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d8cfd8, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: linear-gradient(#d8cfd8, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d8cfd8, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.modalDialog2{
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog2:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog2 > div {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d8cfd8, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: linear-gradient(#d8cfd8, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d8cfd8, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 5% auto 0;
padding:25px;;
position: relative;
width: 800px;
}
.close {
/*background: linear-gradient(#d8cfd8, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
color: #000;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
text-align: center;
top: 0px;
width: 24px;
margin: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;  
}
  .close-2{
    color: #000;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    width: 24px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover, .close-2:hover { color:white; }
  .tab_container {
  /*min-height: 100%;*/
   overflow: auto;
  /* padding: 10px;*/
    display:none;
    background-color: #fff;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 760px;
  height:300px;
  }
  .tab_container ul{
   float:left;
   width:220px;
  text-align:left;
  }
   #pop_tab div{

float: left;
padding: 23px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#p1{display:block;}
#s1{display:block;}
#c1{display:block;}
#f1{display:block;}
#o1{display:block;}

/* TABS starts HERE */
.tabs input[type=radio] {
      position: absolute;
      top: -9999px;
      left: -9999px;
  }
.tabs {
    width: 760px;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    /*position: relative;*/
    padding: 0;
  }
  .tabs li{
    float: left;
  }
  .tabs label {
      display: block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .tabs label:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    top: 0;
  }

  [id^=tab]:checked + label {
    background: #9DBA60;
    color: white;
    top: 0;
  }

     [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
      display: block;
  }
    .tab-content{
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 140%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #9DBA60;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    /*top: 53px;*/
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
  }
    /* TABS ends HERE */
```

any help will be appreciated. there are two links on the site one is using wordpress header and other is using codeigniter header
     1) Wordpress Header
       http://aws1.chemfreecom.com/
     2) using codeigniter header
       http://aws1.chemfreecom.com/search
now codeigniter header working perfectly fine but i am having issue with wordpress header as same HTML/CSS is not working with it.

Comment: Post some HTML as well.

Comment: Actually HTML is quite lengthy as its dynamic i'm using PHP to generate some data so its not small so if you can visit the site links i have provided, the name of css file is custom.css you can view source and can see it,

Comment: Per the guidelines of posting on SO, you should include a minimal example in your question. A link to a jsfiddle is also helpful. If you end up fixing the issue at the two links you posted, this question becomes irrelevant to the community at large.

Comment: i understand what you mean my problem is that its working fine if i use simple html with above css and on link /search its working fine but only problem where i'm using header of wordpress and then loading same CSS. i hope you understand becasue if i post only the HTML than i know this code works fine.

Comment: This issue can be closed as i have fixed it, it was class tabs in custom.css which i posted here was conflicting with class tabs in style.css of wordpress. i changed it from tabs to tabs01 and problem resolved.